# I have a simple code for reactjs but is showing is declared but its value is never read

Tags: reactjs

```
welcome.js 
import React, { Component } from 'react'
class welcome extends Component
{
    render()
   {
       return <h1>Class Component</h1>
   }
}
export default welcome


App.js

import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Greet from './components/Greet'
import welcome from './components/welcome'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Greet />
      <welcome />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So basically in welcome.js i have a code for rendering hello rahul and i have exported that and i have imported that in App.js but it showing welcome is declared but never used please help

Comment: import component name starts with capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with naming. React assumes every tag beginning with a small letter is native (f ex a `<div>` or `<table>`). You have to name your own components with capital letters.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Greet from './components/Greet'
import Welcome from './components/Welcome'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Greet />
      <Welcome />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It's also a good idea to name your files with components with capital letters, to make them easy to identify.

Comment: but it is necessary to use naming with capitals

Comment: Yes, if you any JSX tag begins with a small letter it will be placed literally into the html (in your case a `<welcome />` tag, which is invalid).

Comment: If this worked for you, would you mind to accept the answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

You are importing a component in lower case letters. React doesn't recognize that as a component. So just restructure it as :

```
import Welcome from './components/Welcome'
```

then do 
`<Welcome/>`

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @ilke444 you are correct. I mixed my comments and answer together.